# Set keep_fnames in Electron + React Native project

Tags: react-native, electron, electron-builder

Currently I am developing a project which relies heavily on `<object>.constructor.name` for data serialization.

The project is based upon electron.js and React Native.

It works fine via `yarn run electron-dev` but fails in production via `yarn run electron-pack`.

Apparently, WebPack and Uglify tend to mangle the function names, so instead of

```
 <myTypeClassName>SomeDataType</myTypeClassName>
 <myTypeClassName>AnotherDataType</myTypeClassName>
```

I get:

```
 <myTypeClassName>t</myTypeClassName>
 <myTypeClassName>e</myTypeClassName>
```

Which fails upon deserialization because neither `t` nor `e` are a valid constructor in the application scope.

If I edit `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.prod.js` and add `keep_fnames` to the `mangle` section of the UglifyJS configuration object, the project works just fine.

However editing it in `node_modules` is not a proper way to go. How can I set this in my `package.json` or whatever to use this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to run `react-scripts eject`, as it seemed to be the only solution to get to the configuration properly.